# Decorator dynamic superclassing

Tags: python, decorator

I have simple decorators for replacing invalid characters in dict values when they are attempted to be retrieved.

```
import types


class ContentInterface(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        raise NotImplementedError


class Content(ContentInterface):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return dict.__getitem__(self, item)


class DictDecorator(ContentInterface):
    def __init__(self, interfaceContent, **config):
        super(DictDecorator, self).__init__()
        self._component = interfaceContent
        self._config = config

    def _replace(self, text):
        return text

    def _check(self, invalidCharacterSet, itemPath):
        pass

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        item = self._component[name]
        if isinstance(item, types.StringTypes):
            newText = self._replace(item)
            invalidCharacterSet = set([char for char in item if char not in newText])
            self._check(invalidCharacterSet, name)
            return newText
        else:
            return self.__class__(item, **self._config)


class ReplaceCommaDecorator(DictDecorator):
    def _replace(self, text):
        return text.replace(",", ' ')


class ReplaceDotDecorator(DictDecorator):
    def _replace(self, text):
        return text.replace('.', ' ')


class ReplaceColonDecorator(DictDecorator):
    def _replace(self, text):
        return text.replace(":", ' ')


class ReplaceSemicolonDecorator(DictDecorator):
    def _replace(self, text):
        return text.replace(";", ' ')
```

I want to use this the following way:

```
dictWithReplacedCharacters =\
ReplaceCommaDecorator(                       # Empty
    ReplaceDotDecorator(                     # Empty
        ReplaceColonDecorator(               # Empty
            ReplaceSemicolonDecorator(       # Empty
                Content({                    # Data
                    '1':u'1A:B;C,D.E',
                    '2':{
                        '21':u'21A:B;C,D.E',
                        '22':u'22A:B;C,D.E',
                    }
                }),
            ),
        ),
    ),
)

print dictWithReplacedCharacters['2']['21']
```

I've got 4 redundant dict objects represented decorators for one data dict.

I want to force the nested statement above to return ReplaceCommaDecorator object inherited from ReplaceDotDecorator inherited from ReplaceColonDecorator inherited from ReplaceSemicolonDecorator inherited from Content containing data. I guess this can be solved in DictDecorator's __new__ method.

Comment: And your question is...?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you're doing is the correct way. I would just write a class that accept a generic set of characters and does the checkings/replacing correctly, so if you want to escape more characters you have to simply pass a set containing all the characters(plus maybe some meta information about how to replace etc.).

In your example the code wont work, since `str.replace` requires two arguments, and you pass only one. Maybe you wanted to delete the character? In this case you should do `replace(character, "")`. Anyway, if you plan to replace only single characters with single characters, then you can take a look at the `str.translate` method and the `maketrans` function in the `string` module.

Otherwise maybe regexes are the way to go(using `re.sub`).

Anyway, a way to do what you request is this:

```
class ContentInterface(dict):
    pass

class Content(ContentInterface):
    pass

class DictDecorator(ContentInterface):

    def __new__(cls, other):
        if isinstance(other, DictDecorator):
            if not issubclass(cls, other.__class__) and not issubclass(other.__class__, cls):
                new_cls = type('NewType', (cls, other.__class__), {})
                return new_cls(other)

        ob = dict.__new__(cls)
        return ob

    def __init__(self, interface, **config):
        super(DictDecorator, self).__init__()
        self._component = interface
        self._config = config

        # just to make the result appear with the content.
        # You may not need this.
        self.update(self._component)

    def _replace(self, text):
        return text

    def _check(self, invalid_char_set, item_path):
        pass

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        item = self._component[name]
        if isinstance(item, basestring):
            new_text = self._replace(item)
            invalid_char_set = set(char for char in item if char not in new_text)
            self._check(invalid_char_set, name)
            return new_text
        else:
            # What you wrote here does not make sense...
            # maybe you wanted: return self._config[name]?
            return super(DictDecorator, self).__getitem__(name)


class ReplaceCommaDecorator(DictDecorator):
    def _replace(self, text):
        return text.replace(",", ' ')


class ReplaceDotDecorator(DictDecorator):
    def _replace(self, text):
        return text.replace('.', ' ')


class ReplaceColonDecorator(DictDecorator):
    def _replace(self, text):
        return text.replace(":", ' ')


class ReplaceSemicolonDecorator(DictDecorator):
    def _replace(self, text):
        return text.replace(";", ' ')
```

And it seems to work:

```
>>> a = Content({'1': u'1A:B;C,D.E', '2': {'21': u'21A:B;C,D.E', '22': u'22A:B;C,D.E'}})
>>> r = ReplaceDotDecorator(ReplaceCommaDecorator(a))
>>> r['1']
u'1A:B;C D E'
>>> r = ReplaceColonDecorator(ReplaceDotDecorator(ReplaceCommaDecorator(a)))
>>> r['1']
u'1A B;C D E'
```

Probably there are better ways of doing this, maybe using metaclasses, but this one is the only way I could think.

edit:

By the way, I think subclassing built-in types is not a really good idea, if you don't know exactly what you are doing:

```
>>> class MyDict(dict): pass
... 
>>> a = MyDict(a=1, b=2)
>>> a
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> a.__class__
<class '__main__.MyDict'>
>>> copy = a.copy()
>>> copy.__class__     # Wrong class.
<type 'dict'>
```

Or another example:

```
>>> class MyDict(dict):
...     def __getitem__(self, key):
...             if key.startswith('a'):
...                     return 'BAD!'
...             return super(MyDict, self).__getitem__(key)
... 
>>> my = MyDict(a=1, b=2)
>>> my['a']
'BAD!'
>>> my['b']
2
>>> my.keys()
['a', 'b']
>>> my.values()   #you'd expect ['BAD!', 2]
[1, 2]
```

So be sure to reimplement every method you're going to use and that might cause similar things.

Comment: Well, trying to "push" a design pattern to do a job is generally not a good idea. Design pattern can often be applied to solve problems, but this does not mean that not using them is a bad thing.
Probably trying to use a pattern where it's not needed(or maybe where an other pattern is better) is worse than not using one at all.
Anyway I will try to see if my answer can be improved for your needs.